# how i can i prevent all the cells from being colored?

Tags: java, apache-poi

My aim is to style the cells of a row with different properties. This is happening using a function styleExceptions(....).  Most of the function works, however the problem i'm facing is that every cell in that row is being colored light green, which should not be happening. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. can anyone help.

```
public static void styleExceptions(CellStyle Exstyle, Font Exfont, Cell cell, AdditiveInformation obj){


    Exfont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
    Exfont.setFontName("Calibri");
    Exstyle.setFont(Exfont);
    Exstyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    Exstyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    Exstyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_DOUBLE);
    Exstyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    Exstyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);


    Object result=cellToType(cell);


    if(result instanceof Double){

        if((Double)result==obj.get_xmonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_xmonthbalance() ||
                (Double)result==obj.get_xmonthendstock()){
                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            }

            else if((Double)result==obj.get_ymonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_ymonthbalance() ||
                    (Double)result==obj.get_ymonthendstock()){

                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_ORANGE.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            }


            else if((Double)result==obj.get_zmonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_zmonthbalance() ||
                    (Double)result==obj.get_zmonthendstock()){

                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            }
    }

}
```

this is the cellToType(...) function:

```
private static Object cellToType(Cell cell){


        Object result=null;
        switch(cell.getCellType()){

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                result= cell.getDateCellValue();
            }
            else
            result=cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
            result=cell.getStringCellValue();
            break; 

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            result=cell.getBooleanCellValue();
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            result=cell.getCellFormula();
            break;  

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is in your AdditiveInformation ?

Comment: its a class, and list<AdditveInformation> list1, is a list that contains the instances of that class

Comment: Are you sure to set the style in Exstyle or is it cell object you have to change? Also, try to alert or print the return value from cellToType(...) function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the comparison you are doing.

```
(Double)result==obj.get_xmonthreq()
```

`==` is used to compare primitive values. You have two options :

1. Either Use `doubleValue()` method `((Double)result).doubleValue() == obj.get_xmonthreq().doubleValue()`
2. Or Use `equals()` method `((Double)result).equals(obj.get_xmonthreq())`

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope it didnt work, it still colored all the cells in that row light green :( 
maybe there's something wrong with the conditions, but i cant seem to spot the mistake

Comment: Did you change all the conditions accordingly?

Comment: Then only way you can find out is by Debugging your styleExceptions method line by line.